# Why would article processing fees be waived for this journal? Is this suspect?

Tags: peer-review, elsevier

Here is the link to the journal: https://www.journals.elsevier.com/computer-methods-and-programs-in-biomedicine-update/

I'm not sure why the fee is waived or if this is a red flag in any way?

Answer (score 3):

Article processing charges are quite often waived for new open access journals (as this one appears to be - Volume 1 is listed as "in progress"). As I understand it the hope is to attract researchers to publish in these journals, even though they might not yet be listed in particular databases (Scopus, PubMed etc.) and don't have impact factors (or other ways to measure journal quality, good or bad). It's a way to kickstart a journal with articles to prove it should be taken seriously (and presumably attract paying submissions later on).

Comment: It is pure marketing.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist But if you are low on funds and your research fits the scope it can - on the other hand - be a great opportunity for authors as well.

Answer (score -1):

It shouldn't be a problem for an established publisher. Perhaps they just wound up with some extra funds and decided this would be good community relations. A smaller press might have gotten a grant for such things, but this just sounds like a feel-good gesture.

It is also possible that they have a need to catapult submissions for some of their journals. But I don't see any negative aspects to it.

Comment: See the other answer; https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/170023/13240 As has been mentioned numerous times on this site, Elsevier is not know for being generous with its extra funds.